# Is there a Jetty equivalent of tomcat admin/manager webapp

Tags: jetty

New to jetty and issue a basic $ mvn:jetty run to start my .war application.

However, I want to see the actual application name and endpoints exposed.

I'm used to using tomcat manager to see a list of running applications and endpoints within the browser.  Is there a jetty equivalent to localhost:8080/manager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no admin console or admin webapp for Jetty.

But, if you have JMX enabled on the server side, you can use any JMX console to see this information. (such as `jconsole` from the Java runtime)

You can also have the server dump its configuration state on startup by setting the following System property:

`-Djava.dump.start=true`

You can even use your JMX console to issue the server configuration dump.  To do this, startup jconsole, goto the `MBean` at the `ObjectName` of `org.eclipse.jetty.server:type=server,id=0` and trigger one of the `dump` operations.

Comment: Having connected to jetty using jconsole, how can I inspect the sessions? There is the org.eclipse.jetty.server.session MBean, but it doesn't include access to the sessions.